# Nesting TAILQ_FOREACH macros - can it be done?

Tags: c++, c, unix

I'm trying to nest one `TAILQ_FOREACH` macro block in `C` code within another macro block of `C` code. After looking at the macro for `TAIILQ_FOREACH` in `/include/sys/queue.h`, I don't think I can do it as it stands. I tried creating another macro called `TAILQ_FOREACH_NEST`, but the hidden fields (i.e. `tqh_first)` are compiling unresolved in the new macro.

For an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <sys/queue.h>

main ()
{
    ...
    TAILQ_FOREACH (myEntry, myHead, Entries) {
        // Do something
        TAILQ_FOREACH (myEntryNest, myHeadNest, Entries) {
          // Search for a duplicate, etc.
        }
    }
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

(myHeadNest is of the same TAILQ type as myHead, but separate iterators)

Comment: What unix version are you using?  At least in FreeBSD there's no problem with nesting `TAILQ_FOREACH` as you are doing.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.x